# How to convert FileInputStream/Source.fromFile to dataframe in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to convert  FileInputStream/Source.fromFile to dataframe, is there a good way?

```
spark2-submit --files /property.yml --class com.mas.Main test.jar
```

---

```
val aa = new FileInputStream("property.yml")
or 
for (line <- Source.fromFile("property.yml").getLines) {
      println(aa)
}
```

Could anybody give some advice?

Comment: What does the file look like? What schema do you expect the DataFrame to have?

Comment: just list a int ,b int. i want to find a api in place of FileInputStream

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your Question but you can do something like this.

```
 val lines = Source.fromFile("/path/to/
 your/file").getLines.toList

 val df = lines.toDF()
```